# Dark colors in Asymptote

Tags: asymptote, technical-drawing

I came across strange color behavior in Asymptote. It seems that colors are darker as they should be when I draw 3D figure. Please consider the figures embedded below.

Any idea or pointer?

[image: figure-1]

[image: figure-2]

Source code for Figure 1:

```
import graph;
import settings;
outformat="pdf";
size(8cm, 4cm, IgnoreAspect);
real xmin=-3.5,xmax=3.5;
real ymin=0,ymax=5;
real f(real x) {return 0 + exp(-abs(x)^2);}
path Cf=graph(f, xmin,xmax, n=400);
path mypoly=buildcycle(pA--(1.64,0)--(0.5,0)--pB,graph(f,0.5,1.64));
draw(Cf);
xaxis(Label("$x$"), xmax=3.6, Arrow(3));
yaxis(Label("$p$"), ymax=1.1, Arrow(3));
filldraw(mypoly, red, black);
```

Source code for Figure 2:

```
import graph3;
import settings;
outformat="pdf";
size(7.5cm,0);
real f(pair x) {return 1 + exp(-abs(x)^2);}
currentprojection=perspective(4,5,2);
limits((-3,-3,-0.2),(3,3,3.2));
xaxis3(Label("$x$",1),blue,arrow=Arrow3);
yaxis3(Label("$y$",1),blue,arrow=Arrow3);
zaxis3(Label("$z$",1),blue,arrow=Arrow3);
path3 p1=(-2.5,-2.5,0)--(2.5,-2.5,0)--(2.5,2.5,0)--(-2.5,2.5,0)--cycle;
path3 p2=scale3(2)*unitcircle3;
draw(p1);
draw(surface(reverse(p1)^^p2,planar=true),red);
draw(surface(f,(-2.5,-2.5),(2.5,2.5),nx=20,Spline),lightgray,meshpen=black+thick(),nolight);
```

Comment: In the next to last line of your second code block, change `red` to `emissive(red)`. That creates a `material` that is always exactly the color `red`, regardless of the lighting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is due to the light source position (in 3D). You can observe the phenomenon by playing with asy and the OpenGl render.
Perhaps you can change current light by adding

```
currentlight=light(0,0,2);
```

and

```
draw(surface(reverse(p1)^^p2,planar=true),red,currentlight);
```

O.G.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  It is usually best if you post complete compilable minimal documents rather than code snippets.